# iOS8 AVAudioSession setActive error

Tags: avaudiosession, ios8, xcode6

I'm testing my app in XCode 6 and find an issue with AVAudioSession in iOS8.

When I call

> [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO error:nil];

I get the following error message:

> AVAudioSession.mm:623: -[AVAudioSession setActive:withOptions:error:]:
>   Deactivating an audio session that has running I/O. All I/O should be
>   stopped or paused prior to deactivating the audio session.

In AVAudioSession.h, it says

> Note that this method will throw an exception in apps linked on or after iOS 8 if the session is set inactive while it has running or paused I/O (e.g. audio queues, players, recorders, converters, remote
>   I/Os, etc.).

But I'm not sure how can I check if there's running I/O and how can I dispose all when I need to reset the audio session.

Comment: Can you explain the context, and give a use case why you want to check if there is running I/O?

Comment: @vladof If there's no such error, I don't need to check running I/O. So the situation is, I want to make sure there's no running I/O when I call setActive:NO

Comment: @Anton not a fix, but I found out that the other library I'm using - pjsip - is controlling start/stop audio session at a lower level. So, the way I handle it is to avoid calling setActive if I know the audio session is already setup. It's just my case. You have to figure out if there's anything else that share the audio session with your app.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved this problem, inserting this code in the method of AVAudioPlayerDelegate.

```
-(void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag{
  [audioPlayer stop];
  [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
}
```

where audioPlayer is a variable declared in the header of my class.

the instruction prepareToPlay should resolve your problem!

Comment: @d4Rk it does for me on iOS 9.3: `[audioPlayer stop]; [audioPlayer prepareToPlay]; [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO error:nil];`

Comment: in my case the same error is caused for video player (AVPlayer) which hasn't these methods at all

Answer (score 1):

I pasued My AVplayer before AVAudioSession setActive NO；

`[self.audioPlayer pause];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO
               withOptions:AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptionNotifyOthersOnDeactivation
                                             error:nil];`

Answer (score 1):

Be warned. If you are playing a movie (even with no sound and the audio track removed) then it will still create an I/O thread which will always cause the above error to be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using AVAudioEngine and AVAudioPlayerNode to play sounds. I meet the same problem. My environment is iOS 10.

I use `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()` to handle AVAudioSession. When I run my app in simulator everything is fine, but when I switch it to my device. It failed.

I suppose that I'm using the same session to handle recording and playing. So it may cause some strange issues. In my case, I record the sound and delay 1s to play it. So when I use `stopRecordingAudio()`, I add this piece of code :

```
if audioEngine.running {
    audioEngine = AVAudioEngine() // var audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
    try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(false)
}
```

After redefining audioEngine, audioEngine had been forced to stop and session was released. Crash is never happened again.

Hope this message could help you.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5, IOS 12**

I use **AVPlayer**, it does not have a **prepareToPlay** method. Therefore, Alessio Campanelli's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26278358/10952522) does not solve my problem.
But I noticed the following

```
player.pause()

print("currentTime:",  player.currentTime().seconds) //currentTime: 4.258164744
print("status:", player.status.rawValue) //status: 1 (readyToPlay)
print("timeControlStatus:", player.timeControlStatus.rawValue) //timeControlStatus: 0 (paused)
print("rate:", player.rate) //rate: 0.0

sleep(1)

print("currentTime:",  player.currentTime().seconds) //currentTime: 4.261325767
print("status:", player.status.rawValue) //status: 1 (readyToPlay)
print("timeControlStatus:", player.timeControlStatus.rawValue) //timeControlStatus: 0 (paused)
print("rate:", player.rate) //rate: 0.0
```

After you call the **pause** method, the player plays the audio file for a while. Although other properties say that it is in a pause.
So the only solution I found is

```
player.pause()
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3.0) {
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(false)
    } catch let error {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

In fact, even 0.1 seconds is sufficient. This is a bad way, but I could not find anything better. If anyone knows how to check when the player stops playing the audio file, let me know.